# Android, RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a background image child inside a relative layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/game_background_main"
    android:id="@+id/mainBackground"
    />
```

I then introduce a TextView after this child inside the relative layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mainBackground"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@color/beige"
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    />
```

Now, on my device at least, the mainBackground image is scaled so that the height is the same as the screen, but the width is then slightly less and so there is a gap on the left and right sides. This is fine.

The problem is the myText text view -- why does its left side start from the left side of the screen and not the left side of the mainBackground image as instructed?

Comment: r u want to see textview first then imageview or imageview & textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ImageView's left side is at the left side of the screen. centerInside only affects the location of the content in the ImageView, not the location of the ImageView.

If you want the ImageView to be centered in the RelativeLayout set `android:gravity="CENTER"` on the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

just put
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainBackground" in  textview tag  & remove
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mainBackground"  from textview tag

hope this might help....

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but that's not what I need -- layout_alignLeft and layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf etc. aren't the same. I think Robby is right, and it has persuaded me to create graphics and XML layout files for every device type. There're no shortcuts (sigh!).